# How to use SQL request data in 2 tables on web page

Tags: html, go, web

I have the go web server it  make SQL request and show the result on WEB page.

This is Go code:

```
func PageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    rows, _ := database.Query("select  .......;")
    defer rows.Close()
    user_current := []User{}
    for rows.Next() {
        p := User{}
        err := rows.Scan(&p.Name1, &p.Name2 )
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        user_current = append(user_current, p)
    }
    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("page.html")
    tmpl.Execute(w, user_current)
}
```

And this is my HTML web page:

```
<table>
     <thead><th>name1</th><th>name2</th></thead>
            {{range . }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.Name1}}</td>
                <td>{{.Name2}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{end}}
</table>
```

I want 2 or multiple tables in web page (data different in tables),  But I don't know how to do this

somthing like this:

```
<table1>
     <thead><th>name1</th><th>name2</th></thead>
            {{range . }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.Name1}}</td>
                <td>{{.Name2}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{end}}
</table1>

<table2>
     <thead><th>sign1</th><th>sign2</th></thead>
            {{range . }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.Sign1}}</td>
                <td>{{.Sign2}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{end}}
</table2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```golang
func PageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var data struct {
        Users []User
        Animals []Animal
    }

    // select users
    rows, err := database.Query("select ... from user")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        u := User{}
        if err := rows.Scan(&u.Field, ...); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        data.Users = append(data.Users, p)
    }

    // select animals
    rows, err := database.Query("select ... from animal")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        a := Animal{}
        if err := rows.Scan(&a.Field, ...); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        data.Animals = append(data.Animals, p)
    }

    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("page.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    if err := tmpl.Execute(w, data); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

template

```html
<table>
     <thead><th>name1</th><th>name2</th></thead>
            {{range .Users }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.Name1}}</td>
                <td>{{.Name2}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{end}}
</table>

<table>
     <thead><th>sign1</th><th>sign2</th></thead>
            {{range .Animals }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{.Sign1}}</td>
                <td>{{.Sign2}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{end}}
</table>
```

Comment: @Serg What's the small problem? *(Note: i've removed the bug from the above code where i was still referencing the old `user_current` as the argument to execute, should have been `data`)*

Comment: Great thanks!! I added a little detail to make the code run for me and, unfortunately, I met a small problem : my table is formed by a simple list, no column and row structure

Comment: @Serg that does not sound small to me, if you're not selecting rows with columns then what are you selecting? what is the db returning back to you? I can't help without knowing the details. If you need help either update your current question, or open a new one since the current one seems to be separate from your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made some updates to code of @mkopriva (thanks to him, please vote for his answer )  but faced problem

code

```
func PageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    type User struct {
        Name1  string
        Name2  string
        Name3  string
    }

    type Check struct {
        Date  string
        Time  string
    }
    
    var Data struct {
        Users []User
        Checks []Check
    }

    rows1, err := database.Query("select  name1, name2, name3 from public.users;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer rows1.Close()

    for rows1.Next() {
        u := User{}
        if err := rows1.Scan(&u.Name1, &u.Name2, &u.Name3); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        Data.Users = append(Data.Users, u)
    }

    rows2, err := database.Query("SELECT date, time FROM public.checktime;")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer rows2.Close()

    for rows2.Next() {
        a := Check{}
        if err := rows2.Scan(&a. Date, &a.Time); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        Data.Checks = append(Data.Checks, a)
    }

    
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/2table.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    if err := tmpl.Execute(w, Data); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

template

```
 <table1>
        <thead><th>name1</th><th>name2</th></thead>
               {{range .Users }}
               <tr>
                   <td>{{.Name1}}</td>
                   <td>{{.Name2}}</td>
                   <td>{{.Name3}}</td>
               </tr>
               {{end}}
</table1>
    
<table2>
    <thead><th>Date</th><th>Time</th></thead>
           {{range .Checks }}
           <tr>
               <td>{{.Date}}</td>
               <td>{{.Time}}</td>
           </tr>
           {{end}}
</table2>
```

problem:

[image]

Comment: table1 & table2 are not valid html tags, use valid html and you'll get what you're looking for.